# Integrate GRASS tool in custom python script, QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis

I'm trying to integrate "r.null" tool in QGIS 2.8 script editor. 
When I try to execute the code I get error message that 'outputs_GRASS7R' is not recognized.

This is the code I'm using:

```
outputs_GRASS7R.NULL_1=processing.runalg('grass7:r.null', outputs_GDALOGRRASTERCALCULATOR_1['OUTPUT'],None,SUN_ELEVATION,False,False,False,False,False,None,0.0,sun_elevation_raster)
```

How can I fix that? do I need to import some specific module? (I tried 'import grass, 'import grass.scripts'. I have the GRASS plug-in installed in QGIS.

And I need to be able to send this code to other people that do not understand python.. so hopefully there is a simple solution.

Comment: Hoping you correctly installed GRASS, it could be sufficient writing `import processing` or `from qgis.core import *`at the beginning of the script.